# Laravel API Routes Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, laravel-5.8

Im new to API and Vue. 
Im working on Laravel 5.8 api.php and controllers and views and it only return 404 Not Found.

this is what ive tried

**api.php**

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::resource('/dashboard/departments', 'DepartmentsController');
 });
```

**Controller**

```
class DepartmentsController extends Controller
{     
   public function index()
  {
  return 'hey';
  }
}
```

Route List

```
 GET|HEAD  | api/dashboard/departments                   | departments.index   | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentsController@index                       | api,auth
```

i tried accessing it by `/127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/departments` and `/127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/departments` but both is not working.

Comment: Only one route for a `Route::resource` ?

Comment: please, enter this command (php artisan route:clear)
And then run the server again (php artisan serve)

Comment: there are more routes, i just show the index and i already run the route:clear

Comment: Does the root page show? 127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: yes the root show

Answer (score 42):

Remember that routes declared in `api.php` will automatically prepend the `/api` prefix, e.g.:

```php
Route::get('/hello', ...)
```

```js
axios.get('/api/hello')
```

Comment: The prefixed urls were also tested, so I don't think this is the solution to this problem.

Comment: It's right there in the question. "i tried accessing it by `/127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/departments`"

Answer (score 7):

Your API routes are within the `api` middleware which requires authentication of type API. If you check out the [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication) documentation you need to have API tokens set up and passed in with your request.

You either need to pass the token in with your request, remove the `api` middleware and have your API routes be unauthenticated, or move the routes that you need to access via browser out of the `api` middleware and into the `web` middleware and routes file.

Comment: You are right. For simple testing to verify if my API works, i.e without implementing any authentications, I follow your suggestion : I simply remove the api middleware for certain API routes so that they are unauthenticated. Hence I can access the API via url like so : http://localhost/mylaravelprojects/myjwtapp/public/api/user. This works. Of course, in real project, I need to implement Authentication, either with Passport or simple JWT.

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 6):

Just add public in url before api.

Like

```
/127.0.0.1:8000/public/api/dashboard/departments
```

Comment: @jeesoon Show your complete URL that you are trying.

Comment: i tried this suggestion /127.0.0.1:8000/public/api/dashboard/departments and the two other /127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/departments and /127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/departments

Comment: Add public keyword before api like this url----> 
   /127.0.0.1:8000/public/api/dashboard/departments

Comment: And why would he do that? There's no "public" prefix specified anywhere in the code.

Comment: It's laravel by default.

Comment: but you can remove public keyword in url some minor change in laravel structure

Comment: It's not in Laravel by default unless your web server is misconfigured.

Answer (score 5):

just run

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, anything related to why we need a `clear` to make it effect？

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still wondering, or it just me.
This is what i did after many trials.

i remove the route::group from my API.php and the prefix('api') from RouteServiceProvider.php and replace it with middleware('web')

this is my **RouteServiceProvider.php** file

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('api')
        ->middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

and this is my **api.php** file

`Route::resource('/dashboard/departments', 'DepartmentsController');`

Comment: How about trying the following instead ? Don't change the content of RouteServiceProvider, so your route will still have a API prefix, in case your other API routes will need authentication. Only change your api.php file to become like you mentioned, so your certain routes like /dashboard/departments are not authenticated. Then you access the API with this url : 127.0.0.1:8000/public/api/dashboard/departments. It should work like mine. But if it doesn't, you can revert to your above solution.

Comment: What is the point of this? If you don't want the API prefix, just put the routes in `web.php`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a REST Client (Imsomnia, Postman) you need to check if you are accepting a JSON response. Place a header in the request named "Accept" and "application/json" as value.

[Header "Accept" with the "application/json" value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8hSf.png)

If the requested route has validations (and you are not sending the header), your response will be the root page (or a 404 Error if you don't have the route in routes/web.php).

Comment: Changing the accept header will have no bearing on whether or not you get a 404.

Comment: This worked for me though the issue wasn't 404. The issue was that the requests to the API endpoint were being redirected to the root endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To run laravel project "replace the host with yours" :

`php artisan serve --host 10.11.222.33 --port 8000`

or possible also this way

`php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8000`

and then call the API

`http://10.11.222.33:8000/api/departments`